# How to add New Application mapping in IIS6 and IIS 7 programmatically using WMI and C#?

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, wmi

My goal is to add php Extension to IIS6 and IIS 7 via Code in C# using WMi (System.Management). I cant use DirectoryEntry.

I am stuck with adding a new ScriptMap Object to IIS 6/IIS7.

I have read some posts at here and there and heard that adding new WMi object from Scratch is difficult.

I want to enable IIS 6/IIS7 to handle php as well as aspx files and be able to process them. I have extracted php zip archive to a directory on my system (not installed it). The propblem is i am able to modify existing ScriptMap objects but i dont get to understand the add a new ScriptMap Objects.

Also i am not sure whether adding the a new extensiuon handler to ScriptMap will solve the problem or not.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about which WMI namespaces you're using on IIS6 and IIS7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kev. 
Yes. Got it. Problem solved through  Thanks Kev . :-)

The solution was

1. to add **"*.php"** extension in **"Extensions"** Property of **ScriptMap** Array and **"ScriptProcessor"** Property to be set to the path of the **"php5isapi.dll".**
2. The second thing was to add the **"Default.php"** (or any other suitable default php document) to zeroth index of **"DefaultDoc"** Array among others like **"Default.aspx, Default.htm, Default.html, Default.asp"** etc.
3. The third thing was to enable/Allow the PHP ISAPI Extension. IIsWebService.EnableExtension did the trick.

Thanks again kev for providing me the starting point.

Comment: @Steve - woo...not sure where I helped there :). Just a note though, you should be using the FastCGI bits for IIS6/7 these days when running PHP. http://www.iis.net/expand/FastCGI

Answer (score -2):

Try the PHP installer, it has an option for IIS.. why reinvent the wheel?

[PHP.net installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php)

Comment: Actually, i am re-inventing the wheel. 

I know that the installer does so automatically,

I also know that we can manually do so via IIS Manager.

I am interested in doing it programmatically.

Comment: @talvi - not helpful, if you're building provisioning systems you need to be able to add and remove scriptmaps/handlermappings programmatically.